# What happens when returning a reversed list like this

Tags: python, return, return-value

I used this code to return a list say [1,2,3,4]

```
return (list.reverse())
```

But it simply wont return the correct result. I had to use

```
list.reverse()
return list
```

why is this happening? and when I break up my issue and do

```
list1 = list.reverse()
```

in console and print list1, it simply prints  "list1"

p.s:- I am a beginner and still learning python.

Comment: Almost every method in Python that modifies an object in-place returns `None`. This is intentional—it means each line is changing at most one thing, either mutating a value or assigning a variable, and so it's easier to get an overview of what's happening by just scanning the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`list.reverse` method doesn't return anything. It works over the elements on the list to which is applied (modifying the list). Hence, returning its result will return `None`. Here's the prof:

```
>>>[].reverse() == None
True
```

If you're trying to return a new list with element in reverse order, this is how you do it:

```
return list[::-1]
```

This is called `slicing` in Python and it's used to work with collections.

---

A small note about *returning none*: These methods don't actually `return None`. They don't return any value. But the result of evaluating a function that doesn't return any values is actually `None` in Python.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Using ```newList = list(reversed(oldList))``` also will work  **```list()``` added, see below comments

Comment: Indeed, but it returns a `reversed` object, not exactly a new list.

Comment: @wnnmaw: that's something slightly different -- `reversed(oldList)` won't return a list, it'll return a `listreverseiterator`.  You'd need `newList = list(reversed(oldList))`.

Comment: @PauloBu and DSM, my mistake, there should be a ```list()``` around that, good catch

Answer (score 5):

It's because `list.reverse()` method reverses list in-place - it *doesn't return* the reversed list. See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`reversed`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
return reversed(list)
```

Comment: it is not returning a list @ndpu

Comment: See my comment under Paulo Bu's answer, you need to surround this with  ```list()```

Comment: @YasasveeAtreya you can create list later if you need to with `list(iter)`. Using reversed can be better for less memory consumption

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you're returning the list reversed, the faster solution is

```
list.reverse()
return list
```

You could do

```
return reversed(list)
```

but that's generally slower and uses more memory, because it needs to create a new object.

The reason list.reverse() doesn't return the object for convenience is to remind you that it modifies the original list.